# Get Text from Text Field Inside Table View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have several rows in my table view, each being an instance of my custom cell class that contains a single UTextField. I've assigned a tag for each, but I need to know how to retrieve each text field text value and assign the values to the appropriate strings.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("paymentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PaymentInfoCell

        cell.selectionStyle = .None
        cell.textField.delegate = self

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell.textField.keyboardType = .NumberPad

            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                cell.textField.placeholder = "Card Number"
                cell.textField.tag = 0
            case 1:
                cell.textField.placeholder = "Security Code"
                cell.textField.tag = 1
            case 2:
                cell.textField.placeholder = "Expiration Month"
                cell.textField.tag = 2
            case 3:
                cell.textField.placeholder = "Expiration Year"
                cell.textField.tag = 3
            default:
                break
            }
        } else {
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                cell.textField.placeholder = "First Name"
                cell.textField.keyboardType = .Default
                cell.textField.tag = 4

                if let firstName = sharedUser.userJSON!["firstName"] {
                    cell.textField.text = firstName as? String
                }
            case 1:
                cell.textField.placeholder = "Last Name"
                cell.textField.keyboardType = .Default
                cell.textField.tag = 5

                if let lastName = sharedUser.userJSON!["lastName"] {
                    cell.textField.text = lastName as? String
                }
            case 2:
                cell.textField.placeholder = "Phone Number"
                cell.textField.keyboardType = .PhonePad
                cell.textField.tag = 6
            case 3:
                cell.textField.placeholder = "Address"
                cell.textField.keyboardType = .EmailAddress
                cell.textField.tag = 7
            case 4:
                cell.textField.placeholder = "City"
                cell.textField.keyboardType = .Default
                cell.textField.tag = 8
            case 5:
                cell.textField.placeholder = "State"
                cell.textField.keyboardType = .Default
                cell.textField.tag = 9
            case 6:
                cell.textField.placeholder = "Zip Code"
                cell.textField.keyboardType = .NumberPad
                cell.textField.tag = 10
            default:
                break
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
```

I can do this, but it doesn't seem like the best option.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        switch textField.tag {
        case 0:
            self.cardNumber = textField.text!
        case 1:
            self.securityCode = textField.text!
        case 2:
            self.expMonth = textField.text!
        case 3:
            self.expYear = textField.text!
        case 4:
            self.firstName = textField.text!
        case 5:
            self.lastName = textField.text!
        case 6:
            self.phoneNumber = textField.text!
        case 7:
            self.address = textField.text!
        case 8:
            self.city = textField.text!
        case 9:
            self.state = textField.text!
        case 10:
            self.zipCode = textField.text!
        default:
            break
        }

        return true
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an array of your placeholders like this

```
let placeholders = ["Card Number", "Security Name", ...]
```

Then you can use this code that is not as redundant

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("paymentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PaymentInfoCell

    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    cell.textField.delegate = self
    let index = indexPath.row + indexPath.section*6 //calculates the index of the text in the array
    cell.textField.placeholder = placeholders[index]
    cell.textField.tag = index

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.textField.keyboardType = .NumberPad
    } else {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            if let firstName = sharedUser.userJSON!["firstName"] {
                cell.textField.text = firstName as? String
            }
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            if let lastName = sharedUser.userJSON!["lastName"] {
                cell.textField.text = lastName as? String
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

You can do the same with your variables, put them in an array and just say

```
variable[textField.tag] = textField.text!
```